# how can i add new item in my products table

Tags: django

here i am about  to add   new item  to  my  products table(db). but  im  facing  an  error like in  snap
i have vendor_id as foreign  key  in my  product table

this is my  view.py

```
    def add1(request):
         obj = Vendor.objects.all()
        return  render_to_response('add_product1.html',{'obj':    
                                                    obj},context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def add_product2(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        val0 = request.GET.get('options')
        val1 = request.GET.get('name')
        val2 = request.GET.get('price')
        val3 = request.GET.get('category_product')
        val4 = request.GET.get('quantity')
        v = Product(Vendor= val0,name=val1,price=val2,category_product=val3,quantity= val4)
        v.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/manage_product')
```

this is model

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateField()
    class Product(models.Model):
    Vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    category_product= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

in  add_product1.html

```
<form action="/add_product2/" method="POST">

     id : <select name='options' >
    {% for Vendor in obj %}
    <option  value='0' >{{Vendor.id}}</option>
    {%endfor%}
    </select><br />

   Product  Name:<input type ='text' name= 'name' value =''></br>
   Price : <input type ='text' name= 'price' value =  ''></br>
   Category_product :<input  type = 'text' name= 'category_product' value = ''></br>
   Quantity: <input  type ='text' name='quantity' value = ''></br>
   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='add' />
   </form>
```

Comment: Fix the formatting, show us the models and post the full error traceback.

Comment: Message is clear : `estore_product.Vendor_id may not be NULL`

Comment: You should make your request in POST, if you change somthing in DB.

Comment: yes chnaged to  post . but  im  facing  same errer

Comment: There isn't `vendor_id` in your `request.GET`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer
we  should do  id in  values

```
id : <select name='my_options' >
{% for Vendor in obj %}
    <option  value='{{Vendor.id}}' >{{Vendor.name}}</option>
    {%endfor%}
    </select><br />
```

then  it  handover  foreign  key  smoothely

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ModelForm, it has some usefull tools like validation, automatic form creation, etc... : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/

ModelForm will put field `Vendor` into a `<select>` input.

Comment: but  im sorry , cant change my  full  code now ,as  this is a part of my  project

Comment: ModelForm uses your existing model to create a form and save it and more stuff, it doesn't take more than 5 minutes to use it.